# I can't see the output screen in vscode

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

vscode also opens notepad instead of running the code when i click run code while writing the c program.

when I run the c code, the open file with the application section comes out.But the output does not come out.The applications are notepad, word, etc.
I have the code runner.this problem happened later.i can only see the output of 1 or 2 codes.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can open as many editors as you like side by side vertically and horizontally. If you already have one editor open, there are multiple ways of opening another editor to the side of the existing one:

Alt click on a file in the Explorer.
Ctrl+\ to split the active editor into two.
Open to the Side (Ctrl+Enter) from the Explorer context menu on a file.
Click the Split Editor button in the upper right of an editor.
Drag and drop a file to any side of the editor region.
Ctrl+Enter macOS: Cmd+Enter in the Quick Open (Ctrl+P) file list.

Comment: thank you, but this is not the answer to my question